# Integrating circuitbreaker, retry and timelimiter in Resilience4j

Tags: execution, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, time-limiting, resilience4j-retry

I am trying to use *Resilience4j* features.

My use case is to combine the 3 modules:

- circuitbreaker
- retry
- timelimiter

I want to combine all these modules and execute the method **only once**.

#### Code

Here is what I have tried.

```java
Supplier<R> supplier = this::doSomething;

timeLimiter.executeFutureSupplier(() -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier));

return Decorators.ofSupplier(supplier)
                .withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker)
                .withRetry(retry)
                .withBulkhead(bulkhead)
                .decorate();
```

#### Issue

My `doSomething()` method **executes twice** instead of expected once.

Has anyone seen this issue earlier?

Answer (score 5):

You are using `timeLimiter.executeFutureSupplier` which executes the `Future` instead of decorating it.

Please use it in exactly this order:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
Supplier<R> supplier = this::doSomething;

CompletableFuture<R> future = Decorators.ofSupplier(supplier)
    .withThreadPoolBulkhead(threadPoolBulkhead)
    .withTimeLimiter(timeLimiter, scheduledExecutorService)
    .withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker)
    .withRetry(retry)
    .get().toCompletableFuture();
```

Comment: What would be the order if a rate limiter was added to the decorators, i.e. where would `withRateLimiter(rateLimiter)` go in the above example?

Comment: After giving some thought to it, the rate limiter should probably go in between bulkhead and time limiter.

Answer (score 3):

As Resilience4J creator [*Robert Winkler* answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60221404/5730279), use the decorator to combine/apply the 3 resilience-patterns on the supplier. Adjust their order as needed for execution and resiliency.

#### Order of decorators has effect on execution

The JavaDoc of the [`Decorators`](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-all/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/decorators/Decorators.java#L31) builder explains the effect of *build-chain order*:

> Decorators are applied in the order of the builder chain.
>
> For example, consider:

```java
Supplier<String> supplier = Decorators
     .ofSupplier(() -> service.method())  // 1. called and result handled in order:
     .withCircuitBreaker(CircuitBreaker.ofDefaults("id"))  // 2. circuit-breaker
     .withRetry(Retry.ofDefaults("id"))  // 3. retry
     .withFallback(CallNotPermittedException.class, 
          e -> service.fallbackMethod())  // 4. fallback
     .decorate();
```

(I added comments to emphasize execution order)

> This results in the following composition when executing the supplier:
> `Fallback(Retry(CircuitBreaker(Supplier)))`
>
> This means the *Supplier* is called first, then its result is handled by the *CircuitBreaker*, then *Retry* and then *Fallback*.

#### Integrating client-side `RateLimiter`

As recommended in Reflectoring's tutorial [Implementing Rate Limiting with Resilience4j - Reflectoring](https://reflectoring.io/rate-limiting-with-resilience4j/#using-ratelimiter-and-retry-together):

> #### Using RateLimiter and Retry Together
>
> [..]
> We would create `RateLimiter` and `Retry` objects as usual. We then decorate a **rate-limited** `Supplier` and **wrap it with** a `Retry`: [example]

#### Order suggestion

Comparing this "Retry with RateLimiter" with above JavaDoc example and answer from Robert I would suggest to choose following execution order:

1. supplier, then decorate in order with resilience:
2. `RateLimiter` (prevent a call if rate-limit exceeded)
3. `TimeLimiter` (time-out a call)
4. `CircuitBreaker` (fail-fast)
5. `Retry` (retry on exceptions)
6. `Fallback` (fallback as last resort)

A suitable reference order is for example auto-configured in the Spring-Boot extension. See the official Guides, Getting started with `resilience4j-spring-boot2` about [Aspect order](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#aspect-order):

> The Resilience4j Aspects order is following:
>
> `Retry ( CircuitBreaker ( RateLimiter ( TimeLimiter ( Bulkhead ( Function ) ) ) ) )`
>
> so Retry is applied at the end (if needed).

### See also:

- Reflectoring tutorial series:

  - [Implementing Retry with Resilience4j](https://reflectoring.io/retry-with-resilience4j/)
  - [Implementing Rate Limiting with Resilience4j](https://reflectoring.io/rate-limiting-with-resilience4j/)
  - [Implementing Timeouts with Resilience4j](https://reflectoring.io/time-limiting-with-resilience4j/)
- SteadyBit: [Retries with resilience4J and how to check in your real world environment](https://www.steadybit.com/blog/retries-with-resilience4j-and-how-to-check-in-your-real-world-environment/?utm_content=bufferf96df&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)